# Find $\lambda\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $4x^{11+\lambda}+7y^{19+\lambda}=1,~5x^6+9y^{14}=1$ has solutions.

Tags: systems-of-equations

> Find all positive integers $\lambda$ such that the system:

> $$\left \{\begin {array}{lll}
> 4x^{11+\lambda}+7y^{19+\lambda}=1\\
> 5x^6+9y^{14}=1\\
> \end{array}
> \right.$$
> has solutions.

I tried to check if some values of $\lambda$ (eg $1,2,3$) give us solutions, but the non-linearity of the system makes me think this is not a good way to start. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure, but is very likely that the number of solutions is small, so perhaps what you have to do is to prove that $\lambda=1,2,3$ works (and maybe other small values) and then try to prove that for $\lambda>n$ this has no solutions by contradiction. Another option is that you have to distinguish between even and odd $\lambda$, so if I where you I would do the cases $\lambda=1,\dots, 10$ and then try to find a general pattern.

Comment: Write $x^6=z$ and $y^{14}=w$ and rewrite the equations. I suppose $x,y\in \Bbb C$?

Comment: What is the source of this problem, please?

Comment: After some simulations with Geogebra, I strongly doubt there are any solutions...

Comment: It has been given as an exercise in Numerical Linear Algebra.

Comment: Sorry but there are $n$ books with this title. Can you give the authors ?

Comment: I find solutions with some **negative** $\lambda$, e.g., $\lambda=-8$ or $\lambda=-10$.

Comment: It's a pity you cannot take $\lambda=-5.$

Comment: @Bazyli Zuczek No for $\lambda=-5$ you do not have real solutions.

Comment: Are you permitted to get help here for your exercises?

Comment: Gerry, there is no such issue.

Comment: Indeed, as mentioned before, it seems that there are no solutions for positive integer $\lambda$. The graphics seem to be a good approach (though we don't have a formal proof).

Comment: For the real case, it suffices to notice that the second equation implies $|x| < 1 \land |y| < 1$ and therefore $|4 x^{\lambda + 11}| \leq 5 x^6 \land |7 y^{\lambda + 19}| \leq 9 y^{14}$, with one of the inequalities being strict.

Comment: _Please_ answer my question about the names of the authors of your book. There are at least 6 books with this title.

Comment: Jean Marie, it is given as an exercise in a course called: Numerical Linear Algebra. The source of the exercise is not given (if any).

Comment: @NikolaosSkout how is this related to numerical linear algebra?

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.- All curve $\Gamma$ of equation $ax^{2m}+by^{2n}=1$ where $a,b,m,n$ are positive integers is symmetric to both axis  because if $(x,y)$ is a point of $\Gamma$ so is for the four points $(\pm x,\pm y)$. Besides $\Gamma$ has a shape like a square and is contained in the square centered at the origine and having side equal to $2$.

When $m$ and $n$ are increased "in uniform way" (like as in this problem) we can see that the curves are disjoint:

in fact, for example, in the system $$\left \{\begin {array}{lll}
4x^{12}+7y^{20}=1\\
5x^6+9y^{14}=1\\\end{array}
\right.$$ we have in the first equation $x=0\Rightarrow y=\sqrt[20]{\frac14}$ and in the second one $x=0\Rightarrow y=\sqrt[14]{\frac15}$ and $$\sqrt[14]{\frac15}\lt\sqrt[20]{\frac14}\iff0.8914....\lt0.9330...$$

Similarly we can see that making $y=0$ in both equations we have values for $x$ such that the corresponding to the first equation is less than the other.

**It clearly follows that there are not solutions for $\lambda$ odd**.

(For $\lambda$ even the corresponding curves are not closed but we can reasoning, I guess,in akin way).

Comment: The shape of curves $\Gamma$ looks more like a rectangle than a square (I wanted to say this).

Comment: See the comment by Maxim.

Comment: @Jean Marie: Good, however the case $\lambda$ even is similar to solve with my way. Thank you.